# How do I make a TypeConverter known to an assembly that is called from a COM library?

Tags: c#, com, type-conversion

I have a c# project that consists of a COM typelib (ComLib), a C# tools classlibrary (ComTools) and a main C# project (ComMaster)that is used as a testbed for the COM typelib.

See the code at the bottom.

When calling the COM object from the ComMaster (not as a com object, but as a 'normal' C# object), everything works fine: The call from ComLib to ComTools works and ComTools finds the TypeConverter located in ComLib. The DoIt function pops up a nice Messagebox saying:

```
Original: Hello
Converted: Hello
```

Now I publish the com lib using `RegAsm ComLib.dll /codebase /tlb:ComLib.tlb`.

**My problem is:**
When I call the COM object from, say, Excel-Vba where I set a reference on the typelib generated with regasm and have this code:

```
Sub TestComLib()
    Dim c As New ComLib.ComLib
    c.DoIt "My Test String"
End Sub
```

Now I get a runtime error saying `"InvalidCastException: 'System.String' can't be converted into 'ComLib.MyClass'"`. Obviously, this comes from the nasty `(T)(object)aString` in ComTools.ToolFunc that gets called when the TypConverter is unable to convert the string to a MyClass.

**Now, my question is:**
How can I hand over the TypeConverter attached to MyClass to the ComTools assembly without setting a reference in ComTools to ComLib (EDIT: this would cause a circular reference!)?

I have found the following issue that seems to be the same (but has not been answered): [TypeConverter from VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4215571/2414426)

EDIT: I have just tried to be more explicit in the attribute of MyClass declaring the type converter: `[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter("ComLib.MyClassConverter, ComLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]`. But it does not help :-(

---

EDIT: **Solution**

Thanks to Simon Mourier, I added the following code to my ComLib class:

```
static ComLib()
{//static constructor, gets called before anything in here gets executed
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Name == Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ComLib)).FullName)
            return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ComLib));
        return null;
    };
}
```

---

Sample Code:
**ComLib (project created as c# classlibrary explicitly exposing an interface):**

```
namespace ComLib
{
    [ComVisible(true), Guid("abcdef00-23aa-46d0-8ba8-c7548fa4d820")]//faked GUID
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IComLib
    {
        void DoIt(string aMsg);
    }

    [ComVisible(true), Guid("abcdef01-23aa-46d0-8ba8-c7548fa4d820")]//faked GUID
    [ProgId("ComLib.ComLib")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ComLib : IComLib
    {
        public void DoIt(string aMsg)
        { 
            try {
                MyClass c = new MyClass();
                //call tool func in ComTools
                c = ComTools.ComTools.ToolFunc<MyClass>(aMsg);
                MessageBox.Show("Original: " + aMsg + "\n" + c.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
    public class MyClass
    {//dummy class wrapping a string
        public string Text {get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClassConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
    {//converter for MyClass allowing conversions from string
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        { return sourceType == typeof(string); }

        public override object ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            var s = value as string;
            if (s != null)
                return new MyClass() {Text = "Converted: " + s};
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The ComLib project references the **ComTools** project which contains the following code:

```
namespace ComTools
{
    public class ComTools
    {
        public static T ToolFunc<T>(string aString)
        {//create an object of the given T type converting it from goiven string value
            System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter typeConverter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            if (typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
            {//called from com, the correct type converter is not found
                return (T) typeConverter.ConvertFrom(aString);//convert using the typeconverter found
            }
            else
            {//last resort: try a cast
               // ******* this throws an error when called from COM,
               // ******* because the correct type converter is not found
               return (T)(object)aString;//will not let me cast directly to T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ComMaster project references only the **ComLib** project and contains the following code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        ComLib.ComLib lib = new ComLib.ComLib();//create an instance of the lib
        lib.DoIt("Hello");//call the exposed function
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is, for some reason, when you're running a non .NET application, some types are not resolved as automatically as they are in a pure .NET context, but there is no evident error or exception raised, all fails gracefully and silently (which is a shame BTW...).

What you need to do is help the system a bit, and attach to the [AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx), something like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Name == Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ComLib)).FullName) // adapt to your needs
            return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ComLib));

        return null;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. Where would I put this piece of code? ComLib? ComTools?

Comment: Anywhere where it will be called before the native code comes in play.