# Providing a TypeConverter through an interface or abstract class

Tags: .net, vb.net, plugins, typeconverter

I am transitioning a project's functionality to plugins with an outgoing interface, and an incoming abstract class implemented by the host. Each plugin stores its configuration in its own class that is transferred to, and saved by the host. These configuration classes are edited by the user inside of a PropertyGrid, then stored, or transferred back to the plugin before execution.

The configurations are pretty standard, and share many of the same properties, so I am trying to provide appropriate TypeConverters directly from the host program, so that each plugin doesn't have to implement their own. The plugins and configuration class look something like this:

```
Public Class MyPlugin
    Implements IPlugin

    Private _myData As PluginData
    Private _host As HostMethods

    ''..stuff..

    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class PluginData
        Friend _someData As String

        <TypeConverter(GetType(HostMethods.MyTypeConverter)), _
            DisplayName("My string data"), _
            DefaultValue("String one")> _
        Public Property SomeData() As String
            Get : Return _someData : End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String) : _someData = value : End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

"`HostMethods`" is an abstract class which the host overrides to provide functionality to the plugins, and is pretty standard:

```
Public MustInherit Class HostMethods
    '..stuff..

    Public MustInherit Class MyTypeConverter : End Class
End Class
```

Then, of course, the host inherits this class, creates an instance, and passes a reference to each plugin to provide its methods:

```
Friend Class HostServices
    Inherits HostMethods
    '..stuff..

    Public Shadows Class MyTypeConverter
        Inherits ComponentModel.StringConverter

        Public Overloads Overrides Function Get StandardValuesSupported(...etc...
    End Class
End Class
```

When setting `<TypeConverter(GetType(HostMethods.MyTypeConverter))>` the PropertyGrid is only seeing the empty class defined in the abstract, and I can't move the code to either the plugin nor the abstract without a circular reference, so **what would be the proper way to expose `MyTypeConverter` to the plugin?** <del>I am passing a reference to the instantiated `HostServices` to the plugins upon initialization ("`_host`"), but have no idea if I can set the `TypeConverter` attribute at run-time easily, and would prefer to have the attribute set at design-time.</del>

---

**Update:** I experimented with adding the attribute at run-time (for example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068453/can-you-assign-a-typeconverter-without-a-typeconverterattribute)), but that doesn't work for me in the end, because I'll have no way of knowing which properties to assign which TypeConverters to. Assigning with an attribute is necessary so that plugin designers can choose the appropriate conversions for their properties.

Additionally, I looked into solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399909/how-do-i-make-a-typeconverter-known-to-an-assembly-that-is-called-from-a-com-lib), which involve manually resolving assembly names, but it would seem that this would require my type converter to be in the same assembly as the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To date I have been unable to directly solve this problem, but for anyone who might stumble upon this with a similar issue, my workaround was as follows:

I created a function within "`HostMethods`" which returns the same data that the TypeConverter would.

```
Public Overrides Function GetTypeConverterData() As String()
    Return myTypeConverterData 'as appropriate...
End Function
```

Each plugin then implements it's own TypeConverter (the thing I was trying to avoid altogether), as necessary, which retrieves data from the host, modifies it as necessary, then returns it in the standard way.

```
Public Class MyPlugin
    ''..other plugin stuff..

    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class PluginData
        Friend _someData As String

        <TypeConverter(GetType(MyPlugin.MyTypeConverter)), _
            DisplayName("My string data"), _
            DefaultValue("String one")> _
        Public Property SomeData() As String
            Get : Return _someData : End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String) : _someData = value : End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class myTypeConverter
        Inherits ComponentModel.StringConverter

        Public Overloads Overrides Function GetStandardValuesSupported(..etc..
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Overloads Overrides Function GetStandardValues(..etc..
            Return MyPlugin._host.GetTypeConverterData()
            'and/or other code, as necessary...
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

It isn't ideal, but at least it is straightforward.